# Grabbing chunks of log files that have multiple matching criteria, but the matching criteria is not on the same line

Tags: linux, grep, logs

code:

```
grep -rI --exclude=*_*.log -B20 -A1 "Status:   Error" > /var/log/alertError.log
```

Input log example:

```
[06/07/20 20:38:53.911]:loopback ST:                  token-src-name() 

[06/07/20 20:38:53.914]:loopback ST:                    Token Value: "DVADER". 

[06/07/20 20:38:53.916]:loopback ST:                  token-text(",OU=users,O=data") 

[06/07/20 20:38:53.919]:loopback ST:    Arg Value: "CN=DVADER,OU=users,O=data". 

[06/07/20 20:38:53.922]:loopback ST:                description("Removed by Termination Process") 

[06/07/20 20:38:53.926]:loopback ST:             token-text("Removed by Termination Process") 

[06/07/20 20:38:53.929]:loopback ST:                  Arg Value: "Removed by Termination Process". 

[06/07/20 20:38:53.943]:loopback ST: DirXML Log Event -------------------

     Driver:   \StarWars\system\Driver Set\User Processor

     Channel:  Subscriber

     Status:   Error

     Message:  Code(-9217) Error in
```

This input log shows a section of the log I want to grab. However I want to match on the date for the days I want to search the log. I am using grep as I can do a recursive search of all log files in a structure. My grep returns all of the data I want, except I now want to exclude chunks of code that is older. So the date is not on all lines. The grep is returning a chunk of code with the switches B and A that I need. So if you saw the entire line, the message and status lines are consistent with multiple operations going on. I could grab all types of Message or status values with this grep command, but I just don't know how to then eliminate all of the results to only those chunks of code that are for a given date range.

Comment: Generally, it's inadvisable to parse XML with regular expressions. Please show a sample of your actual log file.

Comment: modified the post. It is just a log file that has some xml data, The XML data isn't needing to keep any structure with what I am doing and won't be reused. Just gleaning data.

Comment: It's unclear for me what you are trying to grep. Could you please describe it more explicit?

Comment: So my grep is grabbing the "Status:   Error" with a number of rows above and below that. That is working fine. What I want to exclude are blocks of code where the dates don't coincide for the day I am wanting to look at. But the date is not included on the same line as the "Status:   Error" line.

I was hoping I could feed in the block of code that this would be spitting out to the file only if that block of code contained the date I was looking for in that block of code.

Comment: Is `log example` your sample input? If so please [edit] your question to show the expected output given that input. Use `find` to **find** files and `grep` to **g/re/p** files to keep your life and code simple, i.e. don't use `grep` to **find** files. There is a big clue in the name of each tool what it's supposed to be used for! In this case though it's extremely unlikely that `grep` will be adequate since you're not trying to just do `g/re/p`, you'll probably need `awk` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `python` solution:

```py
with open("log.txt") as f:                                  # open file log.txt
    lines = f.readlines()                                   # load lines
    nonempty = filter(lambda x: x.strip() != "", lines)     # filter out empty lines
    newlines = []                                           # list for out result lines
    for l in nonempty:                                      # iterate lines
        l = l.rstrip()                                      # cut '\n' from the right of each line
        last_idx = len(newlines) - 1                        # index of the last element in the list
        if l.startswith(" "):                               # this lines are lines with your traceback
            newlines[last_idx] += l                         # add to the "normal" log element
        else:                                               # this are "normal" elements
            newlines.append(l)                              # add them to the list

    print("\n".join(newlines))                              # create output and print to stdout
```

This output contains "Status" and "Date" on the same line and you could `grep` it

Place it (say `normalize.py`) near you log file (say `log.txt`) and run with `python3 normalize.py`

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear but is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk -v tgt='06/07/20' '
    /^\[/ { prt() }
    NF { rec = rec $0 ORS }
    END { prt() }

    function prt() {
        if ( index(rec,tgt) == 2 ) {
            printf "%s", rec
        }
        rec = ""
    }
' file
[06/07/20 20:38:53.911]:loopback ST:                  token-src-name()
[06/07/20 20:38:53.914]:loopback ST:                    Token Value: "DVADER".
[06/07/20 20:38:53.916]:loopback ST:                  token-text(",OU=users,O=data")
[06/07/20 20:38:53.919]:loopback ST:    Arg Value: "CN=DVADER,OU=users,O=data".
[06/07/20 20:38:53.922]:loopback ST:                description("Removed by Termination Process")
[06/07/20 20:38:53.926]:loopback ST:             token-text("Removed by Termination Process")
[06/07/20 20:38:53.929]:loopback ST:                  Arg Value: "Removed by Termination Process".
[06/07/20 20:38:53.943]:loopback ST: DirXML Log Event -------------------
     Driver:   \StarWars\system\Driver Set\User Processor
     Channel:  Subscriber
     Status:   Error
     Message:  Code(-9217) Error in
```

or maybe this?

```
$ awk -v tgt='06/07/20' '
    /^\[/ { prt() }
    NF { rec = rec $0 ORS }
    END { prt() }

    function prt() {
        if ( (index(rec,tgt) == 2) && (rec ~ /Status:[[:space:]]+Error/) ) {
            printf "%s", rec
        }
        rec = ""
    }
' file
[06/07/20 20:38:53.943]:loopback ST: DirXML Log Event -------------------
     Driver:   \StarWars\system\Driver Set\User Processor
     Channel:  Subscriber
     Status:   Error
     Message:  Code(-9217) Error in
```

You can call awk from `find` easily, e.g.:

```
find . -type f -name '*.log' -exec awk '....' {} +
```